# How do I allows application to access email database including received messages, sent messages, user names, and passwords?

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie.

I am building an application which can query data of email(messages, sent messages, user names, and passwords). The email is application of a Samsung.

I figure out the provider of email (Samsung) application is

```
"content://com.samsung.android.email.provider"
```

After my application requires permission for it

```
com.samsung.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER and com.samsung.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER.
```

Then I added permission with `com.samsung.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER` and `com.samsung.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER.` But It still can not query data of email.

```
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.samsung.android.email.provider");
final Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

I am wondering if my application may be need signature or privileged. 
I used this command to investigate:

```
adb -s <device> shell pm list permissions -f
```

What I get is the following sequence data:

```
permission:com.samsung.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER
package:com.samsung.android.email.provider
label:Access email provider data
description:Allows application to access email database including received messages, sent messages, user names, and passwords
protectionLevel:signature|privileged
```

How do I can pass the protection?

Comment: Starting with Android 23, you need runtime and manifest permission grants